# Query about opengl, glut, glew

Tags: opengl

Is there not a simple sdk for opengl why there are glut or glew and what are the written using? Which one should I use? There are so many frameworks out there that it is so confusing? Why there isn't just one sdk for opengl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why there are glut or glew and what are the written using?

GLUT, GLFW and similar frameworks exist, because the system level interfaces to create a window and a OpenGL context are *extremely* versatile in what they can do, but it also takes a lot of code, just to create a window and them some more to create the OpenGL context. …and then some lots more of code to also do things like UI event management and so on.

These system level APIs are that verbose, because on a system level, you don't want to pin down what you can and can not do with these APIs.

So the three calls

```
glutInitDisplayMode(…);
glutCreateWindow(…);
glutMainLoop();
```

encapsulate about 1.5k lines of code dealing with just the system. But then with GLUT you don't get nice buttons, menu bars and the likes. For that you'd use a different framework, like Qt, which has even more code, but uses the same system level APIs as GLUT does. Same goes for GLFW and so on.

GLEW we have, because OpenGL can be extended and the system level interface for extending it is again down for minimalism and flexibility.

> Why there isn't just one sdk for opengl?

Because in the end OpenGL is a system level API and the "SDK" comes ready-to-use with your regular system default compiler.

If you want to, you can create OpenGL programs without GLEW, GLUT and so on. But it is tedious.

Comment: @Jitendra Tiwari The main differences between GLUT and GLFW are that GLUT hasn't changed for 15 years and it lays claim on the main loop, which is both its strength and its weakness, depending on the context. It is a _simple_ SDK convenient for developing _simple_ prototypes.

Comment: @user3078414: That's true as far as the "official" GLUT specification goes. However, the only still maintained implementation today, freeglut, has made some improvements, and you can write your own event loop lwith that ike you can do with GLFW.

Comment: @derhass, thanks for your concern, I was writing about _**"official"**_ GLUT, else I would have written _**FreeGLUT**_. I have been in correspondence with MJK quite a few times so far and I'm aware of his reasons for disallowing further development of "official"  GLUT. Yet, I would dare not say it isn't being maintained. One of the consequences of its being "frozen" in its plain state for so long is its ubiquitous implementation.